Why aren't I receiving file attachments from formsubmit.co?
I am using webflow to built a form and need to receive files, as well as other information. I am successfully receiving the email messages as I expect, and according to my logging, I am sending the file correctly... but no file seems to be attached to the responses I get?
fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/my@email.com", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json(); // Parse JSON response
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("FormSubmit Response Data:", response); // Log the actual response data
            console.log("formData after submission: ", [...formData]); // Log formData contents
            const success = document.querySelector(".w-form-done");
            const errorElement = document.querySelector(".w-form-fail");
            success.style.display = "block";
            errorElement.style.display = "none";
            form.style.display = "none";
        }).catch(function(fetchError) {
            console.error("Error:", fetchError);
            const errorElement = document.querySelector(".w-form-fail");
            errorElement.style.display = "block";
        });
    });
});

[console of form submission - file appears to be submitting as expected](https://i.sstatic.net/Fy7BMvQV.png)

You don't need to set the Content-Type manually:
When sending a FormData object via fetch, you shouldn’t manually set the Content-Type header. The browser does this automatically, including the multipart/form-data boundary required for sending files. If you set it yourself, the file data might not be processed correctly, and this could be the reason why you're not receiving the attachments.
Make sure that FormData includes your file:
If your form has a file input, simply passing the form reference to FormData will automatically include the file. No need to append it manually unless you're trying to do something specific/custom.


https://formsubmit.co/documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

